# in/of the environment

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-of

> I'm predicting the future **of** the environment. (1)
>   I'm predicting the future **in** the environment. (2)

I said (1) is correct but my friend said (2). Which is correct?

Analyze future -> predict the "future" | "future" = environment's future

Comment: It depends on which you're predicting -- the future of the environment itself, of the future of things in the environment.

Comment: "the future of the environment itself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that in this situation 1 would be correct.